# Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have written the following code for fetching data from database:

```
function getnotificationAction()
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $userId = $session->get('userid');

    $entitymanager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $notification = $entitymanager->getRepository('IGCNotificationBundle:Notifications');
    $userNotification = $entitymanager->getRepository('IGCNotificationBundle:Usernotifications');
    $query = $entitymanager
                 ->createQuery("SELECT n.notificationid, n.title,n.notificationmessage, u.creationdate, u.notificationid, u.messagestatus From IGCNotificationBundle:Notifications AS n JOIN IGCNotificationBundle:Usernotifications AS u ON u.notificationid = n.notificationid WHERE u.userId = :userId ORDER BY n.creationdate DESC")->setParameter('userId', userId);

    $notifications = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('IGCNotificationBundle:Default:notification.html.twig', array('notifications' => $notifications));
} }
```

But it is giving:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 203: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON' 500 Internal Server Error - QueryException 1 linked Exception: QueryException »

Comment: may be remove `AS` `IGCNotificationBundle:Notifications n JOIN IGCNotificationBundle:Usernotifications u`

Comment: Hi thanks for reply i have tried this but facing the same error

Comment: As far as I see it you're trying to execute `SQL`... you need to rewrite it to `DQL` (Docrine Query Language). Please update your question with entities' structure...

Comment: hi @jperovic i dont know how to convert this in DQL

Comment: can any one convert this sql query in dql query

Comment: I could, but I need to see your entity relations ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 203: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON' 500 Internal Server Error - QueryException 1 linked Exception: QueryException »
```

I think you should replace your keyword 'ON' with a 'WITH' .

**extract from doc :**

> Joins between arbitrary entities are now possible in DQL by using the
>   syntax `FROM Foo f JOIN Bar b WITH f.id = b.id`.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue with Symfony 3 doctrine, It works. Have to use `WITH` instead of `ON`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the bellow code its work for you

```
function getnotificationAction() {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $userId = $session->get('userid');
    $entitymanager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $notification = $entitymanager->getRepository('IGCNotificationBundle:Notifications');
    $userNotification = $entitymanager->getRepository('IGCNotificationBundle:Usernotifications');
    $query = $entitymanager->createQuery("SELECT n.notificationid, n.title,n.notificationmessage, u.creationdate, u.notificationid, u.messagestatus From IGCNotificationBundle:Notifications AS n JOIN IGCNotificationBundle:Usernotifications AS u WITH u.notificationid = n.notificationid WHERE u.userId = :userId ORDER BY n.creationdate DESC")->setParameter('userId', userId);
    $notifications = $query->getResult();
    return $this->render('IGCNotificationBundle:Default:notification.html.twig', array('notifications' => $notifications));
}
```