# Symfony2 Query Using Left Join on Two Tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, left-join

I am trying to retrieve product information from a query that looks in one table for an identifier and matches that on another to get the product id then looks in the product table to get the information for the product(s). For some reason I cannot get this query to run successful. Any help would me much appreciated!!!

```
 $query = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT p
            FROM WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product p
            LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing l
                ON l.product = p.id
            LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingAma la
                ON la.id = l.id
            WHERE la.standardProductIdValue LIKE :stringValue
            AND   p.account = :account_id')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->setParameter('stringValue', "%1234567890%")
            ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);
```

Product Table

```
 |id|product_name      |account_id|
 ----------------------------------
 |1|Test Product 1     |74        | 
 |2|Test Product 2     |74        | 
 |3|Test Product 3     |74        | 
 |4|Test Product 4     |74        | 
 |5|Test Product 5     |74        |
```

Listing Table

```
 |id|product_id       |
 ----------------------
 |1|1                 |
 |2|1                 |
 |3|2                 |
 |4|3                 |
 |5|1                 |
 |6|3                 |
 |7|5                 |
```

ListingAma Table

```
 |id|standardProductIdValue |
 ----------------------------
 |1|1234567890              |
 |2|1234567890              |
 |3|AAAAAAAAAA              |
 |4|BBBBBBBBBB              |
 |5|1234567890              |
 |6|CCCCCCCCCC              |
 |7|0000000000              |
```

The Listing and ListingAma tables are a base class (Listing) and and extended class (ListingAma) so they share the ID number in each table.

I want to return product information for any query that has  standardProductIdValue equaling "1234567890". In this case it should retrieve rows 1,2 and 5 and then in the listing table it should sync that with Product id #1 and just return "Test Product 1".

My query above creates this error in Symfony:

```
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 163: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got &#039;ON&#039; (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post, I was able to find out what the issue was:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467428/error-expected-doctrine-orm-query-lexert-with-got-on
```

Here Is The Correct Code:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT p
        FROM WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product p
        LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing l
            WITH l.product = p.id
        LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingAma la
            WITH la.id = l.id
        WHERE la.standardProductIdValue LIKE :stringValue
        AND   p.account = :account_id')
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->setParameter('stringValue', "%B00AM204Q6%")
        ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:

```
    $query = $em->createQuery("
        SELECT p
        FROM WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product p
        LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing l
            ON l.product = p.id
        LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingAma la
            ON la.id = l.id
        WHERE la.standardProductIdValue LIKE :stringValue")
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->setParameter("stringValue", "%1234567890%");
```

Is this failed too with same error?

Comment: Yes, same error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 147: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got &#039;ON&#039; (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: Same error. [Syntax Error] line 0, col 131: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got &#039;ON&#039; (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: Figured it out, posted the results at the bottom of my original post.