# Symfony 2, SQL ManyToMany get client without relations

Tags: sql, symfony, repository

I have problem with my custom repository.

I have 3 entities : Client, Campaign and CampaignClient.

I want to get all clients who **are not** in (this) campaign. 
My Entities are simple. 
Client -> OneMany <- CampaignCLient, 
Campaign -> OneMany <- CampaingClient

My Query ( I feel that my query is wrong but I DON'T KNOW WHY ? ):

```
->createQuery('SELECT c FROM MainBundle:Client c '
                . 'LEFT JOIN MainBundle:CampaignClient cc WITH (cc.client = c.id)'
                . 'WHERE cc.campaign != :id ')
        ->setParameter(':id', $id)
```

My Client Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $id;
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CampaignClient", mappedBy="client", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $campaigns;
```

My Campaign Entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CampaignClient", mappedBy="campaign", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $clients;
```

And my CampaignClient Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="campaigns")
 */
private $client;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Campaign", inversedBy="clients")
 */
private $campaign;
```

EDIT: I use MySql

I tried to ask my sql by code:

```
SELECT * FROM client c
LEFT JOIN campaignclient cc ON c.id = cc.client_id
WHERE cc.campaign_id = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

And it's ok but If I will change Where clausule to cc.campaign_id = NULL or cc.camaign_id != 1 it return 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c FROM MainBundle:Client c LEFT JOIN MainBundle:CampaignClient cc WITH (cc.client = c.id)
WHERE cc.campaign != :id
```

Try and replace WITH (...) with ON ... so it looks like this:

```
SELECT c FROM MainBundle:Client c LEFT JOIN MainBundle:CampaignClient cc ON cc.client = c.id
    WHERE cc.campaign != :id
```

Comment: I got error : Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'
I use MySql

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467428/error-expected-doctrine-orm-query-lexert-with-got-on